# Additional condition on Shopware default product slider

Tags: shopware

On my website I have product slider which is showing newest articles. I have protected and not-protected articles. I want slider to show only not-protected articles. I added additional condition like in [documentation](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/customer-streams-extension/#add-own-condition)

But I'm getting error

```
Exception: Condition MyConditions\Conditions\CategoryCondition not supported in .../src/engine/Shopware/Bundle/SearchBundleDBAL/QueryBuilderFactory.php on line 242
```

How can I implement this or what is the reason of the exception?

Comment: Have you also built and registered a handler?
If I follow the documentation it works.
Maybe you can share some more code?